# how to get exact local time based on longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, time, latitude-longitude

first of all thx for the intention.

In my database I have the exact latitude and longitude of a certain places. How can I maybe in the frontEnd (Javascript, btw I have django as backend) get the local time of these places?

many thx in advance.

Comment: you'd need to determine the location in terms of a country/state/province ... since timezones are not neat lines on a map!

Comment: You probably want to get the timezone for a lat lng. Then its quite trivial to get the current time for that. Probably better to do it on the Python side, so it can be saved/cached, and not bloat the frontend. https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinderL. There is a JS lib as well if you not bothered with the above. https://github.com/darkskyapp/tz-lookup/

Comment: thx for the answer and the suggestions so much. Now I go with the python one--> problem solved.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates